# Functional Groups Identification

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Identify functional groups of the following organic molecule:
>
> [image: Structure]
>
> **A**. ketone, alkene, carboxylic acid, ester
> **B**. alkyne, ester, carboxylic acid, aldehyde
> **C**. carboxylic acid, alkene, ketone, ester
> **D**. ester, aldehyde, carboxylic acid, alkene

I am not sure what the answer it. I know it can't be **B** because there is no alkyne triple bond. However, shouldn't an alkene only exist in a straight chain? I know there is a COOH carboxylic acid, R-O-R' ether and a CHO aldehyde, and a double bond O for a ketone.

I was wondering if someone could tell the right answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "an alkene only exist in a straight chain"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohexa-1,3-diene is perfectly an alkene, in that case a conjugated *diene*.

Comment: Also check these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactone esters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only right choice is D, because there is an ester, even though this ester is intramolecular, being made of the bridge -CO-O- in the lower part of the molecule. The aldehyde group is -CHO in the R.H.S. The carboxylic acid is in the upper part of the middle. And there are two alkene groups in the cycle at L.H.S.

Comment: Keying on ester is useless. All the choices have ester and carboxylic acid in them.

Comment: I'd call it a lactone, rather than intramolecular ester.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be **A&C** because there is no *aldehyde* in both options, and also it can't be **B** 'cause there's no alkyne–**FG** in the compound, thus the only option left is **D** since the compound contains *ester(lactone), aldehyde, carboxylic and alkene* FGs as state in the option **D**

So I think **D** is the right answer.